# iOS SwiftUI - Remove top space and back button doesn't work

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                VStack{
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            .font(.title2)
                        Text("profile")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            

                        }) {

                            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill.badge.plus")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(height: 24)
                            
                            Text("subscribe")
                            
                            Button(action: {

                            }) {
                                Image("share_black_24dp")
                                    .tint(Color.white)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            }
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)

                    }
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20, height: 40)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .background(Color.teal)
                    
                }

                // .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton)

                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

where does

```
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

need to be!?

I also tried it for NavigationView and it doesn't work

Comment: Which back button are you referring to?  Your code is drawing a left arrow (chevron) and the word profile, but that isn't a back button.  If I remove your three .navigationBar lines, extra space appears, so they are doing their job.  Is this your root view, or are you coming here from another view?

Comment: @vacawama Sounds like a common mistake of nested `NavigationView`s to me too

Comment: yes I'm coming to this view from the main view and I want the toolbar to be the way I create it and not some forced default crap. Besides the entire navigationview/link is beyond dumb, why can't they do it like android, why does apple need to do everything needlessly complicated

Comment: Only the first view should have a NavigationView.  If your main view has a NavigationView, then don't add a second one here.

Comment: Oh ok so I can use navigationlinks in the child view then without it also having navigationview? That makes sense, thanks! I'll check if you create it as answer but I'll do it tomorrow because I'm off for today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you have multiple `NavigationView`s.

`NavigationView` creates a new stack of views.  Only your main view should have a `NavigationView`.  The child views can use `NavigationLink` to push new views, but they should not create another `NavigationView`.

Think of it like this.  `NavigationView` creates that stack to hold the views, and `NavigationLink` pushes a new view onto the stack.  You only want to create one stack.

So, get rid of `NavigationView` in your `View` above, because it is linked from the main view which creates the `NavigationView`.  Then, your code to hide the navigation bar will work as you expect.